# How to save status of checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have gone through many questions on StackOverflow but could not get this code working. The checkbox is always checked when the activity is created.

My Code :

```
    @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            chb1.setChecked(load1());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            save1(chb1.isChecked());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
           chb1.setChecked(load1());
        }
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_lock);
    chb1 = (CheckBox)  findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    chb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(chb1.isChecked())
                    {
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                        editor.commit();
    }
private boolean load1() { 
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences1.getBoolean("checked", false);
    }
private void save1(final boolean isChecked) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
            editor.commit();
    }
```

How can i make this work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are storing in preference but not fetching from preference that's what you have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need onStart since it will run onResume anyway.

Another point is you set listener on checkbox and only save when the checkbox is checked, so it will never set to false, and that's why your checkbox always checked when you open the activity.

Here is a fixed version, I hope it's work. :)

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    save1(chb1.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setCheckBoxFromSave();
}

private void setCheckBoxFromSave() {
    bool loadedChecked = load1();
    if (chb1.isChecked() != loadedChecked) {
        chb1.setChecked(loadedChecked);
    }
}

private static final String KEY_CHECKED_SAVE = "checked";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_lock);

    chb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    setCheckBoxFromSave();
    chb1.setOncheckListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheck(boolean check) {
            save1(check);
        }
    });
}

private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

private boolean load1() { 
    return getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(KEY_CHECKED_SAVE, false);
}
private void save1(final boolean isChecked) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
    editor.putBoolean(KEY_CHECKED_SAVE, true);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but the problem persists. I have edited the question and added load1() and save1() methods, is there any problem with these methods?

Comment: I have update the code to be more clear. Maybe some syntax mistakes but It should work already since the logic is correct. If it still not work, please check setOncheckListener is really called by adding Log.e and check the variable is it correct or not. And is your checkbox is checked from the beginning? If yes, try set chb1.setChecked(false) in onCreate. If it still set, there must be something else incorrect now. Make sure you check every boolean variables in every step. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

**Save state** of **CheckBox** by **SharedPreference**:

**onClick** of CheckBox:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("sp_title", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checked", chb1.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

Now **get** **state** of **CheckBox**:

on **onCreate()**:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("sp_title", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences1.getBoolean("checked", false);
```

Now **set** **state** of **Checkbox**:

```
chb1.setChecked(isChecked);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I have checkedTextViews within a navigation drawer, so i wasn't able to set each checkbox individually as i'm using mDrawerList. I used mDrawerList.setItemchecked(int position, boolean value) and used getDefaultPreferences to load the values onCreate and the same to save onItemClick. Thanks